# Which jar file should I use to import

Tags: hibernate

Which jar file should I use to import the following?

```
import org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator;
import org.hibernate.validator.Validator;
```

Answer (score 0):

These classes are contained in:

```
 hibernate-annotations-3.x.x.x.jar

 hibernate-validator-3.x.x.x.jar
```

You will need to pick the version matching your hibernate version.